# Why is my update not persisting?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an anonymous type (grps) populated from a linq query.  One of the field (DYs) contains an array.

if I run this code:

```
grps.ElementAt(0).Product = "kkk";
```

I get a compile error.

If I run this code I get no errors but the value is unchanged.

```
grps.ElementAt(0).DYs[0] = 19;
Console.WriteLine(grps.ElementAt(0).DYs[0]); // not 19
```

If, however, I do a foreach on grps and then do a nested step through of each array, I can change the values of the array and they are reported, within the nested loop, as changed.  Outside the nested loop they are still unchanged.

I need to make changes to the values in the arrays in my anonymous type but I cannot figure out how.

This has annoyed and confused me because I spent time writing code that I thought was working ok, but turns out not to without producing any errors.

---

UPDATE

The upshot to this is that as usual when I have encountered a problem it's because I've forgotten to stick ToList() on the end of something.

Comment: Can you post a short but complete progam that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you would get a compile-error for the first one - you're trying to set a property in an anonymous type, and you can't do that in C#. In the second case, you're not trying to set a property - you're just mutating an array. That's an entirely different operation - it's like doing something like:

```
private readonly StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("hello");
...
builder.Append("Stuff");
```

This changes the contents of the object which `builder` refers to; it doesn't change the value of the `builder` variable. Anonymous type properties are read-only in the sense that you can't change their values - but if the value is a reference to a mutable object, you can still mutate the object.

Now, in the second form: you're calling `ElementAt` twice. That means it will execute the query again the second time - creating a new instance, and thus a new array. The object whose array you changed earlier has gone. However, if you do this:

```
var list = grps.ToList();
list[0].DYs[0] = 19;
Console.WriteLine(list[0].DYs[0]);
```

it *will* print out 19.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why is my update not persisting?

Unless you used something like `.ToList()` on your linq query, you are generating a different sequence with each call to `ElementAt(0)`.

The definition of `grps` is key here... If it's linq... that's your problem.

#### why does one compile, but the other not compile?

You are asking for an array `.DYs`, and then you are changing part of the array (then throwing the array away.).  That's why the second statement compiles, but the first does not.